# Change the Order of _.groupBy() result Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, lodash

Everyone, this is my Array  Structure

```
let data = [
    {"name": "ragupathi", "siteID": 10},
    {"name": "abi","siteID": 13},
    {"name": "mahesh", "siteID": 12},
]
```

i want group data based on siteID 
so I am using groupBy siteID

> **let sample = _.groupBy(data,'siteID');**

the current output is :

```
{
  "10": [
    {
      "name": "ragupathi",
      "siteID": 10
    }

  ],
  "12": [
    {
      "name": "mahesh",
      "siteID": 12
    }
  ],
  "13": [
    {
      "name": "abi",
      "siteID": 13
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am Expecting output name in ASC order

```
{
  "13": [
    {
      "name": "abi",
      "siteID": 13
    }
  ],
  "10": [
    {
      "name": "mahesh",
      "siteID": 12
    }
  ],
  "12": [
   {
      "name": "ragupathi",
      "siteID": 10
    }
   ],
}
```

1. GroupBy SiteID
2. Grouped Output  based on properties of Object Name

Comment: [The order of object properties is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), so you cannot expect `groupBy` to "order" the resulting properties in any way.

Comment: This is not possible. The output object has integer keys. In ES6, it will always be *traversed* in ascending order of those numbers irrespective of the order in which they were inserted. So, 10 -> 12 -> 13. You might want to [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/3082296) and [this blog post](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html)

Comment: @adiga Yup... But if any possible to Change order give some idea I am new in javascript

Comment: @Ragupathi if you need to order the items, you should use an array instead. Just map the final object by populating a new array where the objects are actually ordered by site ID instead.

Comment: BTW, `groupBy` returns an array of all objects with same `siteID`. But, why does your output have only one object in each array?

Comment: @adiga based on siteID I will get external data

Comment: @adiga sorry I posted wrong code this now i changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/125981 may help you

Answer (score 0):

The property order for objects in ES6 is:

- The keys that are integer indices, **in ascending numeric order**.
- Then, all other string keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.
- Lastly, all symbol keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.

[Reference](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html)

The output object has integer keys. No matter which order you insert the keys to the object, it will always be printed in the order: 10 -> 12 -> 13

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as an output. `Map` objects hold key-value pairs and **remember the original insertion order of the keys**

Create an object with each unique `siteID` as key and an array with single object as value. Then [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object based on the `name` of each object. Then create a `Map` from these sorted entries (Check the browser's console for the output. Stack snippets displays `Map` as an empty object)

```js
let data = [
    {"name": "ragupathi", "siteID": 10},
    {"name": "abi", "siteID": 13},
    {"name": "abi","siteID": 13},
    {"name": "mahesh", "siteID": 12},
    {"name": "abi", "siteID": 13},
    {"name": "abi", "siteID": 13},
    {"name": "ragupathi", "siteID": 10}
]

const uniqueSiteGroups = {};
data.forEach(o => uniqueSiteGroups[o.siteID] = [o])

const sortedEntries = Object.entries(uniqueSiteGroups)
                        .sort((a, b) => a[1][0].name.localeCompare(b[1][0].name))

const map = new Map(sortedEntries)

console.log(map) // check the browser's console
```

Answer (score 0):

Since order of the props is not guaranteed you have to utilize [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or other methods to get the sorting and the output you need.

You can use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) like this:

```js
let data = [{"name": "ragupathi", "siteID": 10},{"name": "abi", "siteID": 13},{"name": "abi","siteID": 13},{"name": "mahesh", "siteID": 12},{"name": "abi", "siteID": 13},{"name": "abi", "siteID": 13},{"name": "ragupathi", "siteID": 10}], 
map = new Map()

data
  .sort((a,b) => b.siteID - a.siteID)
  .forEach(x => map.set(x.siteID, [...(map.get(x.siteID) || []), x] || [x]))

console.log(map) // The map object output in your browser console
console.log(Array.from(map.values())) // The siteIds in array form
```

Once you have them in the `map` object then you can access the groups easily by `siteID` like `map.get(13)` and you will get the array of the grouped items for the siteID of 13.

You can also always get the order in which you have stored the keys in the map via the [Map.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) method.